# How to set half hour and 45-minute time zones without worrying about DST changes in Linux?

Tags: linux, timezone

Currently I am setting time zone GMT+5 on my Linux CentOS 7 machine by linking /etc/localtime to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT-5.

I want to create a zone info file for example `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT-5:30` that enables me to set the current timezone to GMT+5:30 without having to worry about DST changes.

I am aware that I could link `/etc/localtime` to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkat`a for example but then I will have to worry about DST changes even if it may not be implemented in the mean time.

Also I am aware of `TZ=GMT+5:30; export $TZ` but I am worried that this approach backfire for some reason in the future.

Comment: 5:30 or 5:45 (as per headline)?

Comment: Why do you think that when you use a timezone file delivered with the system and updated through the usual channels, you will have to worry about DST changes? If your computer's displayed time should match the official time in Kolkata, using that tz file is the proper thing to do.

Comment: Because I have services running on this machine that depends on non-DST time zones which are in 'Etc/GMT+-<hour>'.  Etc time zones are guaranteed not to be updated. I am asking for something that provides the same guarantee but as  'GMT+-<hour1>::<minute> format not only hours.